# odoo 16: how can i concatenate 2 fields in qweb PDF to generate barcode?

Tags: concatenation, qweb, odoo-16

please check my code below, i want to **conatenate 2 fields o.name & o.ref** to **generate barcode** in **qweb pdf**, how i can do it, please help. the report code is as below:

```
<template id="report_patient_id_card">
   <t t-call="web.html_container">
      <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
         <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
         <div>
            <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/Code128/'+o.name + o.ref" style="width:200px;height:50px" alt="Barcode"/>
         </div>
         </t>
      </t>
   </t>
</template>
```

note: for a single value o.name its working fine, i can scan & check value through mobile app, but when concatenate 2 fields **o.name + o.ref** , its generating barcode in PDF but it is not showing anything when scanning through mobile app. means the generated barcode is not valid.

please help how i can do it?

regards

Comment: thanks @KJ but still searching for help.